# random sampling 1/3 of genome .fasta

Tags: fasta, genome, reformat

I have a genome of about 2 gb composed by scaffolds
I would random sample the genome.

I used reformat.sh but the output was only a scaffold. I need 1/3 of the total genome...

```
>LGKD01000001.1 Octopus bimaculoides isolate UCB-OBI-ISO-001 Scaffold4_contig_1, whole genome shotgun sequence
GAACAGCATGAATGTTAAAACtgaaatggatgatgatgatgatgatgatgatgatgatggcagcaacAGCCatgattatatttaatatgttgttagttataatcataataatgatgataatgttgataacaaTAATGGTTGCAATAATG
>KQ415657.1 Octopus bimaculoides isolate UCB-OBI-ISO-001 unplaced genomic scaffold Scaffold5, whole genome shotgun sequence
tatatatatatagtcaattcgagGATGTTAGATCGACAATGGGGATTATAGAATCCCACAAAAAATTCCACTGGT
>LGKD01000032.1 Octopus bimaculoides isolate UCB-OBI-ISO-001 Scaffold12_contig_1, whole genome shotgun sequence
GAAGTGGTAAAGAGTgcgatgcgctgaaaaaagagagaacagtacttgaaatGTGGTTTCATTCTagtagtaaat
>LGKD01000033.1 Octopus bimaculoides isolate UCB-OBI-ISO-001 Scaffold16_contig_1, whole genome shotgun sequence
ctgaTCAACAGAatagggccaatcattcttcatgacaatgctcgaccacacgttttaCTAATGA
>LGKD01000034.1 Octopus bimaculoides isolate UCB-OBI-ISO-001 Scaffold22_contig_1, whole genome shotgun sequence
TTATCTATATACGagaatattatctatatataaaggaataccaaaaaaacaagaacaacgggtcattcggaattttcttt
```

There is a script able to do this?

Comment: You mean 1/3 of the scaffolds or 1/3 of the sequence?

Comment: I would obtain a file with 1/3 of the total n. of scaffolds

Comment: It should not be difficult to create a script for this. Read the input file and, for each scaffold, throw a dice, a random number between 1 and 3. If it is 1, write the scaffold, if not, continue reading until the next.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you have a 2Gb file with N sequences and you would like to pick 1/3 random sequences out of this file? (again outputted in a standard fasta file?)

Comment: yes, this is the problem